# How to add custom language syntax highlighter to markdown code block in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Using markdown code blocks with `css` gives you CSS syntax highlighting, but doesn't give me my custom language "Link" syntax highlighting (I have the tmLanguage.json for it [here](https://github.com/tunebond/link/blob/0743df744a6497c73780234f74ad96758d34b77e/code/syntaxes/link.tmLanguage.json)).

[image]

How do I have it use the custom language syntax highlighter in my Markdown code blocks with triple backticks in VSCode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSCode does not have an easy way to do this, and support was marked as out of scope ([#71888](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71888)). Extensions can manually inject support for custom languages into markdown code fences:

https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-fenced-code-block-grammar-injection-example/tree/master

In package.json, add a language and grammar for markdown injection, replacing LANGUAGENAME with your language id:

```json
{
    …
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [
            …,
            {
                "id": "LANGUAGENAME-markdown-injection"
            }
        ],
        "grammars": [
            …,
            {
                "language": "LANGUAGENAME-markdown-injection",
                "scopeName": "markdown.LANGUAGENAME.codeblock",
                "path": "./syntaxes/LANGUAGENAME-markdown-injection.json",
                "injectTo": [
                    "text.html.markdown"
                ],
                "embeddedLanguages": {
                    "meta.embedded.block.LANGUAGENAME": "LANGUAGENAME"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Add a file `./syntaxes/LANGUAGENAME-markdown-injection.json`, replacing LANGUAGENAME with your language identifier or scope as needed:

```json
{
    "fileTypes": [],
    "injectionSelector": "L:text.html.markdown",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#LANGUAGENAME-code-block"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "LANGUAGENAME-code-block": {
            "begin": "(^|\\G)(\\s*)(\\`{3,}|~{3,})\\s*(?i:(LANGUAGENAME)(\\s+[^`~]*)?$)",
            "name": "markup.fenced_code.block.markdown",
            "end": "(^|\\G)(\\2|\\s{0,3})(\\3)\\s*$",
            "beginCaptures": {
                "3": {
                    "name": "punctuation.definition.markdown"
                },
                "4": {
                    "name": "fenced_code.block.language.markdown"
                },
                "5": {
                    "name": "fenced_code.block.language.attributes.markdown"
                }
            },
            "endCaptures": {
                "3": {
                    "name": "punctuation.definition.markdown"
                }
            },
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "begin": "(^|\\G)(\\s*)(.*)",
                    "while": "(^|\\G)(?!\\s*([`~]{3,})\\s*$)",
                    "contentName": "meta.embedded.block.LANGUAGENAME",
                    "patterns": [
                        {
                            "include": "source.LANGUAGENAME"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "markdown.LANGUAGENAME.codeblock"
}
```